# Weird stuff going on in terminal and emacs since upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: xorg, xterm

I can't really describe the slightly odd behaviour of my terminal window and occasionally also on emacs, but here's a picture of it happening:

[image: Weird stuff]

If I press CTRL+L, it disappears. What could cause this? It started happening once I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10, so I expect something broke there. It's a zsh shell using xterm. The computer in question is an Acer Aspire Timeline 4810T.

Comment: looks like problem with xorg or video driver. does it happen outside of the terminal?

Comment: Yes, in emacs. Though not as often as it does in xterm.

Comment: @Seamus: it could be a bug anywhere from the font data to the video card through the client font handling library, other client X libraries, the X server, your X video driver. Does the bug show up with other fonts, or at other sizes? Does moving the window, or hiding it and showing it again, or resizing it change anything?

Comment: You might more help if you ask on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Moving the window, or alt-tabbing away from it and then back both make the lines disappear. Also, the problem seems not to happen if I use gnome shell rather than xterm.

Comment: Also, the problem does not seem to happen if I use gnome-terminal rather than xterm. but it does happen in emacs.

Comment: Oh man I just find out I have this problem too. It seems to be something wrong with `xterm` itself, because it doesn't happen in `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Bug reported here: https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xterm/+bug/663469?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with xorg and a [fix exists](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/635258).